# Matching repeating words in a row by regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to find a replace repeating words in the string, but only if the are next to each other or separated by a space. For example:

```
"<number> <number>" -> "<number>"
"<number><number>"-> "<number>"
```

but not

```
"<number> test <number>" -> "<number> test <number>"
```

I have tried this:

```
import re
re.sub(f"(.+)(?=\<number>+)","", label).strip()
```

but it would give the wrong result for the last test option.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r"(<number>)(?:\s*<number>)+",r"\1", label).strip()` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFfqxS/1))?

Comment: Did you try to use f-strings because you want to use a dynamic variable? Or is '<number>' a static substring you need to be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r"(<number>)(?:\s*<number>)+",r"\1", label).strip()\
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFfqxS/1). *Details*:

- `(<number>)` - Group 1: a `<number>` string
- `(?:\s*<number>)+` - one or more occurrences of the following sequence of patterns:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `<number>` - a `<number>` string

The `\1` is the replacement backreference to the Group 1 value.

[Python test](https://ideone.com/714ral):

```py
import re
text = '"<number> <number>", "<number><number>", not "<number> test <number>"'
print( re.sub(r"(<number>)(?:\s*<number>)+", r'\1', text) )
# => "<number>", "<number>", not "<number> test <number>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(<number>\s*){2,}
```

- `(<number>\s*)` Capture **group 1**, match `<number>` followed by optional chars
- `{2,}` Repeat 2 or more times

In the replacement use group 1.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olTZj2/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "<number> <number>",
    "<number><number>",
    "not <number> test <number>",
    " <number>   <number><number>  <number>     test"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"(<number>\s*){2,}", r"\1", s))
```

Output

```
<number>
<number>
not <number> test <number>
 <number>     test
```

Comment: @JvdV The trailing spaces are now in the group 1 so you keep them.